# Javascript: non-effective replaces causes problems

Tags: javascript

i have this simple code which is replacing the first span with a div ,

here is LIVE examples :

1. the original working one : http://jsfiddle.net/SNmLJ/5/
2. the one with the changes : http://jsfiddle.net/SNmLJ/6/

-

```
var pn = "parentNode" , rc = "replaceChild";
var elem = document.getElementsByTagName('span')[0];
var newE = document.createElement('div');

newE.innerHTML = 'test';
elem[pn][rc](newE , elem);
```

the code is perfectly working , so i tried to short the code a bit so i did this :

```
var pn = "parentNode" , rc = "replaceChild";
var newE = document.createElement('div');

newE.innerHTML = 'test';
document.getElementsByTagName('span')[0][pn][rc](newE , elem);
```

as you see i took the "elem" var out and replace the value in the bottom of the code ,
i don't know why it's not working but i guess the problem is causes of the "document" object in the first of the line.

- single question : why it's not working properly , what have been gone wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you forgot that the `elem` variable was used also in the last parameter passed to the `replaceChild` function.
Here is **elem** at the end, but you have erased the definition:

`document.getElementsByTagName('span')[0][pn][rc](newE ,`**`elem`**`);`

Answer (score 0):

What's `elem` in the non-working code?

(Hint: nothing ;)